# What is size limit of mail in mfmailcomposer to send mail

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

when i send mail using mfmailcomposer, mailComposer gets crashed when i attached large size files to my mailcomposer. how to overcome this problem and please tell me how much size of data including attachment files send using mfmailcomposer ?

Comment: Could you show us the crash log?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677622/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crash-because-of-large-attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two limits to take in factor:

1. Device memory, if you'll exceed it your app will most likely crash. (don't know if that's the case here)
2. File size limit by your Mail provider (on SMTP). For example, Gmail limit is 25MB per email in one file. [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en)  so if your app isn't ready for a failed response there's a good possibilty for a crash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a specified limit. However, there is always a limit to how much memory your device has.

Note the API doesn't add a file, it is adding a `NSData` instance, possibly copying it, so the required memory can be very big.